# Thinned Poisson Process with inlaBRU

Tags: r

I'm trying to simulate a thinned Poisson process in the plane and then fit a log Gaussian cox process to it using the lgcp function from inlaBRU. The process is thinned using a half normal detection function along transects which serve as my samplers. However, when I go to include the samplers/transects in the model I get a CRS error. I am lost as to why this is happening because the process I am simulating is in the plane not on the surface of the earth. Adding to my confusion, the model successfully fits if samplers the samplers passed in are stored in a SpatialPoints or SpatialPolygons dataframe. I  have attached an example below that will reproduce the error.

```
#libraries------------------------------------
library(INLA)
library(inlabru)
library(rgeos)

#functions------------------------------------
homogenousPoissionProcess <- function(rate, xlim, ylim){

  area <- (xlim[2]-xlim[1]) * (ylim[2]-ylim[1])
  npoints <- rpois(n=1, lambda=rate*area)
  xloc <- runif(npoints, min=xlim[1], max=xlim[2])
  yloc <- runif(npoints, min=ylim[1], max=ylim[2])

  pts <- as.matrix(cbind(xloc, yloc))
  pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, data.frame(a=1:nrow(pts)))

  return(pts)
}

half_normal <- function(sigma){
  func <- function(x){exp(-x^2/(2*sigma^2))}
  return(func)
}

buildTransects <- function(xs, ys){
  transects <- lapply(1:nrow(xs), FUN=function(i){
    Line(matrix(c(xs[i, 1], ys[i, 1], xs[i, 2], ys[i, 2]), nrow=2, byrow=TRUE))
  })

  transects <- lapply(1:length(transects), FUN=function(i){
    Lines(transects[[i]], ID=letters[i])})

  transects <- SpatialLines(transects)

  df <- data.frame(len = sapply(1:length(transects), function(i) gLength(transects[i, ])))
  rownames(df) <- sapply(1:length(transects), function(i) transects@lines[[i]]@ID)

  transects <- SpatialLinesDataFrame(transects, df)

  return(transects)
}

thinnedPointProcess <- function(rate, xlim, ylim, transects, distfunc){

  point_process <- homogenousPoissionProcess(rate, xlim, ylim)
  pts <- point_process@coords
  trans <- transects@lines
  distance <- rep(Inf, nrow(pts))

  idx <- rep(NA, nrow(pts)) #index to keep
  prob_missed <- 1 #changed to prob missed

  for(i in 1:nrow(pts)){
    prob_missed <- 1
    pt_curr <- SpatialPoints(matrix(c(pts[i,]), nrow=1))

    for(j in 1:length(trans)){
      tran_curr <- SpatialLines(list(trans[[j]]))
      s <- gDistance(pt_curr, tran_curr) #distance from jth transcet
      prob_missed <- prob_missed * (1- distfunc(s))
      distance[i] <- min(distance[i], s)
    }

    idx[i] <- as.logical(rbinom(1, 1, 1-prob_missed))
  }

  pts <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts[idx,], data.frame(distance = distance[idx]))

  return(pts)
}

#main-----------------------------------------

rate <- 650 / (100 * 50) #rate per unit area
xlim <- c(0, 100)
ylim <- c(0, 50)

bnd <- spoly(data.frame(x=c(xlim[1], xlim[2], xlim[2], xlim[1]), 
                        y=c(ylim[1], ylim[1], ylim[2], ylim[2])))

xs <- as.matrix(cbind(seq(5, 95, by=10), seq(5, 95, by=10)))
ys <- as.matrix(cbind(rep(0, 10), rep(50, 10)))
transects2 <- buildTransects(xs, ys)

distfunc <- half_normal(2)

set.seed(2021)
pts2 <- list(points=thinnedPointProcess(rate, xlim, ylim, transects2, distfunc),
             ppoly=bnd, samplers=transects2)


mesh <- inla.mesh.2d(boundary=bnd, max.n=20) #20 for computaional ease

pts2$mesh <- mesh

W <- 2 #half width

#redefine dectection function to work in model
hn <- function(distance, lsig){    
  exp(-0.5*(distance/exp(lsig))^2)
}

matern2 <- inla.spde2.pcmatern(pts2$mesh,
                               prior.sigma = c(2, 0.01), #same priors as in tutorial
                               prior.range = c(50, 0.01))


cmp2 = ~ mySPDE(map = coordinates, model = matern2) + #components from tutorial
  lsig + 
  Intercept 


formula2 = coordinates + distance ~ mySPDE +  #formula from tutorial
  log(hn(distance, lsig)) +
  log(1/W) +
  Intercept 

#ERROR IS HERE
fit2 <- lgcp(components = cmp2,
             data = pts2$points,
             samplers = pts2$samplers, #works if you comment out this line
             formula = formula2)
```

Comment: "I get a CRS error." - could you edit your question to show this error? I might then be able to answer it before INLA's 320Mb package is downloaded...

Comment: My bad the CRS error is "Error in spTransform(sp3d, CRSobj = CRS("+proj=geocent +ellps=sphere +R=1.00")) : 
  No transformation possible from NA reference system"